# How to avoid SASS adding a space to the asterisk (*) symbol?

Tags: css, sass

**SASS CODE:**

```
#{'body > *:not(.this)'} {
    background: red;
}
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
body > *:not(.this) {
    background: red;
}
```

**ACTUAL RESULT**

```
body > * :not(.this) { //<-- SASS adds a space between * and :
    background:red;
}
```

No matter what I try, SASS keeps adding an unnecessary space. How can I avoid this from happening? The space blocks the functionality of the not-selector.

Comment: This might be your IDE's (or editor) default behavior.  With IDE or Editor are you using?

Comment: I am using CodeKit 3. Output style: Compressed. Debug info: None. Use the libsass compiler. Run autoprefixer on the css file. I will try some settings.

Comment: You are correct @RohanRao. The setting "Output style: Compressed" messed it up, any other setting left it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

This was not due to SASS. I was using CodeKit 3 and the following SASS setting messed it up:

**Output style:** Compressed

Put this on any other output style and you can avoid the above.